# meteor return unique documents from collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am a newbie to development and Meteor brought me in.
I have the following scripts:

In the Lib Folder

```
Transactions = new Meteor.Collection('transaction');
```

Server

```
Meteor.publish('trans',function(){
    return Transactions.find({});
});
```

Client

```
Meteor.subscribe('trans');
```

My Collection named Transactions contains the following objects

```
{
  date: Date,
  amount: Number,
  userid: Meteor.userId()
}
```

I would like to return a list of all the different dates contained in the collection, without any duplicate.

Comment: By "unique dates", do you mean a list of *all* dates in the collection in which each date appears exactly once, or a list of *just* the dates that appear in only one document?

Comment: My collection has dates like  'Date1, Date1,Date2, Date2,Date1,Date3,Date4,Date3,Date5,Date5' like that.. And I neeed to return 'Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4 and Date5'

Comment: @MaheshBabu, you mean distinct values, and not unique?

Comment: @PeppeL-G   I hope this comment will make it clear........ My collection has dates like 'Date1, Date1,Date2, Date2,Date1,Date3,Date4,Date3,Date5,Date5' like that.. And I neeed to return 'Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4 and Date5'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Template.view.helpers({

viewDate:function(){
 var transactions = Transactions.find({userid:Meteor.userId()}).fetch();
return _.uniq(transactions, false, function(transaction) {return transaction.date});
}

});
```

This made my day... Thank You @chrishillonline

Answer (score 0):

return _.uniq(Transactions.find({}), function(transaction)
{return JSON.stringify(transaction)});

Comment: Can you give me a mongoDb object to try it please

Comment: if you can use a .fetch()

Comment: var transactions = Transactions.find().fetch()

Comment: _.uniq(transactions, false, function(transaction) {return transa ction.date});

Comment: I hope you are asking about the fields I have in my mongo

Comment: var uniqTransIds = _.map(_.uniq(Transactions.find().fetch(), function(transaction) {return transaction.date}), function(uniqTransaction){return uniqTransaction._id};

return Transactions.find({_id: {$in: uniqTransIds}})